# jqGrid is sorting only in ascending order in version 4.4.3

Tags: jqgrid

This is my code. When I click on <kbd>asc</kbd> or <kbd>desc</kbd> it always sorts data in ascending order only. Can you please let me know, do I need to add anything?

```
if (typeof jQuery("#plist")[0] != UNDEF && jQuery("#plist")[0].grid) {
    jQuery("#plist").GridUnload();
} 
jQuery("#plist").jqGrid({
    url: URL,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colModel: colModelData,
    pager: '#pagerTrade',
    rowNum: 80,
    gridview: true,
    rowList: [80, 160, 240],
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "550",
    width: "auto",
    viewsortcols: [true, 'vertical', true],
    multiselect: true,
    onSortCol: function(index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
        //alert("index:"+index+", columnIndex:" +columnIndex + ", sortOrder:" +sortOrder);
        var colSort = {};
        colSort.index = getColumnIndex("plist", columnIndex);
        colSort.direction = sortOrder;
        var colSortList = [ colSort ];
        var pageNo = getPageNo("plist");
        var rowCount = getRowCount("plist");
        //Function CAll()
        return 'stop';
    },
    gridComplete: function() {

    }
});
```

Server side code:

```
if(!CommonUtil.isNullOrEmpty(request.getParameter("sidx"))){
                sortByColumn = request.getParameter("sidx");
            }
            if(!CommonUtil.isNullOrEmpty(request.getParameter("sord"))){
                sortByOrder = request.getParameter("sord");
            }
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, Thank you for your suggestion. Will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You use `datatype: 'json'` **without** `loadonce: true` option. It means that *there server* (see `url : URL`) is responsible for sorting, paging and filtering/searching of data. If the user click on the sorting icon then jqGrid just send one more request to the server using `sidx` and `sord` parameters, which corresponds the clicked column. I guess that your server code *ignores* `sord` parameter and the server just returns the page of data sorted in ascending order only. You need fix you server code or to change your code to use use `loadonce: true` option.

Comment: Yes @Oleg, Code is ignoring the sidx parameter, when i get this value using requst.getParamter then it gives me null value. Can you give me any suggestion here how can i get value from this or how can i change it?

Comment: @SurajBhandari: What is "requst.getParamter"? jqGrid is pure JavaScript library. You posted only client side code. We found out that *the origin of your current problem is inside your server code*. It's important to know. You should solve the problem yourself or to post more information about your server code.

Comment: Hi @Oleg i was talking about my server side code, i have pasted my code also. I am not getting sidx value in server side code, it is null.If it is null how can i get column name then?

Comment: @SurajBhandari: There are a lot of languages, which you can use on the server side, a lot of frameworks and so on. The code, which you posed helps absolutely not to understand what you do. It's not enough to post code fragment without posing more details...

Comment: you r right, but my question is i am not getting column value in server side code irrespective of language. Since sidx will remain same for all the languages, so when i am try to get it's value it is giving me null. My question is is there any client side changes is required to get value of sidx in server side.

Comment: @SurajBhandari: I repeat you that your server code have **no relation** to jqGrid and your previous question. I personally use C# in the server code, but even C# code written for ASP.NET MVC is absolutely another as C# code which uses  WFC method, WebMethod or ASMX web service or General ASHX Handler, ...

Comment: @SurajBhandari: I suggest you to post **separate question** about your server problem because it has no relation to jqGrid. You should clear describe which server side language, which framework and so on you use. If I search for `request.getParameter` I find more Java examples, which I don't use. Even the information about Java gives the readers not so much information. The server side code in Java will be absolutely different in case of usage Netty, Spring MVC and so on. You should clear define the framefork, which you use on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Your onSortCol event return always **stop**, which causes the grid not to send the needed data to your server and your sort is always not performed (populate is not executed).

```
onSortCol: function(index, columnIndex, sortOrder) {
        //alert("index:"+index+", columnIndex:" +columnIndex + ", sortOrder:" +sortOrder);
        var colSort = {};
        colSort.index = getColumnIndex("plist", columnIndex);
        colSort.direction = sortOrder;
        var colSortList = [ colSort ];
        var pageNo = getPageNo("plist");
        var rowCount = getRowCount("plist");
        //Function CAll()
        return 'stop';   <===== HERE STOP RETURNED
    },
```

To prewent this just remove the **return stop** and you will get your parameters at server